How to create a Composable that I can drag up and down on it to increase its height
I am required to create a UI in Jetpack Compose of a card that initially takes some constant height but the user can drag on it to increase or decrease its height and show more or less content. It's very similar to a Bottom Sheet in its behavior but I don't want my UI to be anchored to the bottom of the screen like how a Bottom Sheet is.
Here's how my card looks now:

Can you tell me how can I do this? I need to increase and decrease the height with user similar to what you have in a Bottom Sheet.

I managed to do it using Compose-Foundation AnchoredDraggable like below:
Things taken into consideration while implementing this:

The card changes height when the user drags it up or down.
The card snaps to the nearest height anchor (collapsed or expanded).
The user can quickly swipe the card up or down to change the card height anchor (collapsed or expanded). Similar to a bottom sheet.

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ExpandableColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current

    // TODO replace these fixed values with calculated values depending on content
    val collapsedHeight = 300.dp
    val expandedHeight = 600.dp

    val state = remember {
        AnchoredDraggableState<CardDragAnchors>(
            initialValue = CardDragAnchors.Collapsed,
            positionalThreshold = { distance: Float -> distance * 0.5f },
            velocityThreshold = { with(density) { 100.dp.toPx() } },
            animationSpec = tween(),
        ).apply {
            updateAnchors(
                DraggableAnchors {
                    CardDragAnchors.Collapsed at with(density) { collapsedHeight.toPx() }
                    CardDragAnchors.Expanded at with(density) { expandedHeight.toPx() }
                }
            )
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(with(density) { state.offset.toDp() })
            .anchoredDraggable(
                state = state,
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                enabled = true,
                reverseDirection = true,
            )
            .then(modifier)
    ) {

        content()

    }
}

private sealed interface CardDragAnchors {
    data object Collapsed : CardDragAnchors
    data object Expanded : CardDragAnchors
}

